# Default ASP.NET Core MVC project won't run

Tags: debugging, ssl, asp.net-core-mvc, iis-express, visual-studio-2019

I created a new ASP.NET Core MVC project with Visual Studio 2019, using the built in default template. I simply ran the project by clicking the green 'play' arrow where it says "IIS Express" (or by pressing F5).  I haven't modified anything, yet when my browser opens up (in this case, Microsoft Edge) I get this:

Can’t connect securely to this page
This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Your TLS security settings aren’t set to the defaults, which could also be causing this error.

I've opened a 'ticket' with Microsoft, but haven't heard anything yet. It may be that there is an issue with my IIS Express installation, but I'm not sure how to figure that out.  I normally prefer to run my ASP.NET MVC local development from my local IIS, but it seems that IIS Express is the default way for Core MVC.

Comment: IIS Express in VS2019 installer should install a self-signed certificate. If you don't make it trusted then all browsers should show a warning, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/self-signed.html#to-trust-self-signed-certificate

Comment: The self-signed certificate is indeed installed and trusted. Problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my install of Visual Studio 2019 by removing all the web (ASP.NET) components, and then modified it again by adding them.  After this, the default ASP.NET Core project does indeed work and debug with IIS Express.

I don't know how my install became corrupted, but it must have been from one of the numerous Visual Studio updates that seem to be released every few days.